# Variable restatement node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, timer

Here is a snippet from a node.js script I am working on.

I am using timers to emulate a tick-by-tick type of environment, in the beginning of the code I set the serverstatus to zero, in the startserver function I access the variable and attempt to reassign it to 1, but when the console.log appears, it reports that the variable is 0.

```
setInterval(report,2000);
var server = setInterval(start, 4000);
var serverstatus = 0;

function report(){
console.log(serverstatus);
};

function start(){
    if (serverstatus == 0){
        var serverstatus = 1;

    };
console.log("tick"")
};
```

What can I do to add one to that number and access it properly from the report function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `var` from `var serverstatus = 1;` so you are setting and testing the global variable by that name, not declaring a new, separate local variable.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f9yuf7qq/

P.S. you also have a syntax error in `console.log("tick"")` with an extra quote.